# What are the clipboard formats for Microsoft Office where you can drop a chart?

Tags: drag-and-drop, ms-office

I'm trying to create a DOCX in memory that I can provide for a Drag & drop operation.

I first tried "Embed Source." However, while it seems to be perfect (DOCX in an OLE wrapper), Word does not use it for drag & drop although it does use it for cut & paste. Is there a way to force Word/Excel/PPT to use "Embed Source?"

Second it uses FileContents sometimes and that also looks like it would work. However while Spy shows it being requested when Word does a drag/drop to Word, it doesn't work when my app is the source. Word does ask my app if it can do FileContents but it never requests the data in that format - even if my app says that is the only format.

SO how can I pass a drag/drop something which includes content controls & charts in it (so RTF, HTML, etc won't work)?

thanks - dave